# Product Images Thumbnail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, thumbnails

I have a product details page and would like to show the product image along several thumbnail pictures of the product, how can I do this in asp.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create thumbnail image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808887/create-thumbnail-image)

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a built-in mechanism for generating image thumbnails:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic handler that will receive an unique identifier for the image (to load the image, from a database, filesystem or from the web), resize it within the generic handler with appropriate code (see jonfen's answer, but I've never tried it; or hit google with "c# resize image") and return the resized image