# working with images in windows phone app - performance

Tags: windows-phone-7, image-processing

I have an app that allows users to take pictures and store them in the IsolatedStorage.  These images are then retrieved to display them in a list.  The app suffers from performance issues when there are more than 30+ images in the list.  It is taking a long time to retrieve these images from the storage and bind them to the list.  A lot of times, the app is just closed by OS because it takes too long.

Also, I think as better resolution devices are coming in the market, the images are getting created with bigger sizes and affecting performance even more.

I need some guidance on how to resolve this.  Couple of things I have though about:
1) how can I asynchronously retrieve every image to be retrieved from IS so the page can load but the images are being retrieved in async fashion.  Any sample code is appreciated.
2) the other approach will be where I create a thumbnail photo of the actual photo (smaller size and resolution) while storing the original photo and use this thumbnail photo in binding to the list later.  If this should be done, then how should I go about processing the image on the fly to create a smaller size thumbnail version of the original photo.

Any other ideas are appreciated as well. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: the reason the app gets closed is more likely memory problems, not the app taking too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to, I would recommend using the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) and making the code that loads images from isolated storage async. The methods that generate the thumbnails can be async as well.

If you cannot do this (add these dependencies to your project), use a BackgroundWorker. Perhaps [this](http://wildermuth.com/2011/01/11/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_9_of_10_Threading) article can help you get started.

This will allow your UI to be responsive while processing continues on threads in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Do not pretend the Isolated Storage as a SQL Server. There will be great performance difference. If you want to process too much data, send them to server.

However, there is a method for getting a thumbnail. You can use it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Also, please check this answer:

[Create thumbnail image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808887/create-thumbnail-image)